# About min values in list

Tags: python

```
 def min_value(L)
```

'''L i s a list of ints that are >= -1. Return the minimum value in L that is >-1. If L doesn't have any value in it other than -1, return -1.'''

```
 ans = -1
 for n in L:
     if n> -1:
        if ans == -1: <------------?? Can someone explain why they are doing this. Isn't ans already equal -1?? Thus processing ans = n every time??
           ans = n 
        else:
           ans = min(ans, n)
 return ans
```

ANYHELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED.

Answer (score 4):

`ans` starts out as `-1`, but the value changes:

```
        if ans == -1:
            ans = n             # Right here
        else:
            ans = min(ans, n)   # And right here
```

If `ans` stays at `-1`, then there are no numbers in the list that are greater than `-1`.

A slightly more readable way of doing this would be:

```
def min_value(L):
    filtered = [n for n in L if n > -1]

    if not filtered:
        return -1
    else:
        return min(filtered)
```

Comment: @DSM: Yep. I've deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave out the `if ans == -1: ans = n` lines, and instead always just execute `ans = min(ans, n)`, then `ans` would remain at -1 instead of changing to the minimum value that's larger than -1.

Here is some slightly shorter alternate code:

```
def min_value(L)
    ans = -1
    for n in L:
        if n > -1:
            ans = min(n, max(ans,n))
    return ans
```

Eg:
`min_value([-2, 3, -4, -5])` gives 3,
`min_value([-2, 3, -4, 2])` gives 2, and
`min_value([-2, -3, -4, -5])` gives -1.

Comment: THIS IS MUCH BETTER FUNCTION AND MUCH EASIER TO UNDERSTAND THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I think this is clearer:

```
def min_value(L):
    try:
        return min(n for n in L if n > -1)
    except ValueError:
        # this gets raised if all n in L are not > -1
        return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def min_value(L):
    return min([i for i in L if i >= -1] or [-1])
```